# Parser Information in Integration

Tags: integration

.I'am new for salesforce Integration.Please explain me with me small example. Please explain following terms very clearly
parser.getcurrentToken(),parser.getcurrentText(),parser.nextToken() what are these terms

```
String JSONContent ='{"isActive":true}';
JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(JSONContent);
 // Advance to the start object marker.
 System.debug('parser.nextToken():'+parser.nextToken());
 //output:START_OBJECT  which represents starting of object (‘{‘)
// Advance to the next value.
 System.debug('parser.nextToken():'+parser.nextValue());
 Boolean isActive = parser.getBooleanValue();
   System.debug('isActive:'+isActive);
```

Answer (score 0):

Read [this blog](https://scotthung.wordpress.com/2015/01/21/how-to-parse-a-json-response-using-salesforces-jsonparser-class/). You will get an Idea about parser methods.